# Error with use of new build tools version: 3.3.0

Tags: trigger.io, forge

I was prompted to download the new forge tools version, and then I've successfully downloaded the version 3.3.0 from https://trigger.io/forge/upgrade/.

Next I've run "source go.sh"

After that, I then run "forge build", and I get the following message:

```
(forge-environment) forge build
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.0
[   INFO] Update result: you already have the latest tools
[   INFO] Your app configuration has changed: we need to rebuild your app
[   INFO] Starting new build
[  ERROR] Forge API call to app/5164f58e8cfb11e1931112313d1adcbe/template went wrong: 
The platform version requested is incompatible with the version of the build tools you 
are using.

Requested Forge platform version: v1.2
Your current build tools version: 3.3.0

Update your build tools from: https://trigger.io/forge/upgrade/
```

Is there an additional setup that I should do?

Answer (score 1):

The v1.2 Trigger.io platform was temporarily incompatible with the newest build tools: we fixed that and pushed out an update.

If you try to run `forge build` again, you should be good to go.

Comment: May need a forge build -f if you ran forge build before and encountered this issue